# Prophet Abraham dream of sacrificing his son

Tags: dream, sacrifice, prophet-ibrahim

I know that the whole incident of Prophet Abraham going to sacrifice his son on the mountaintop came to him in the form of a dream.
He dreamt of sacrificing his son and upon waking he concluded that it was Allah command to sacrifice his son. How did he conclude this? It could have been very much possible that it was a Shaitan dream.

What exactly happened that night in his dream? Please elaborate.

Comment: If you can look in the old testament, search the "Binding of Isaac"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could not have been a dream from Shaitan because Abraham عليه السلام  was a prophet. The dreams of prophets are true and are a form of revelation. Revelation is protected from Shaitan.  Abraham knew this and that is why he didn't ignore it. Similarly Ishmael\Isaac  عليه السلام  knew this and this is why he called it a command from Allah and told his father to obey it.

> أول ما بدئ به رسول الله صلى الله علي وسلم من الوحي، الرؤيا الصادقة في النوم، فكان لا يرى رؤيا إلا جاءت مثل فلق الصبح
>
> The commencement of the Divine Inspiration to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) was in the form of good righteous (true) dreams in his sleep. He never had a dream but that it came true like bright day light.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6982)</sup>

> ورؤيا الأنبياء وحي، فإنها معصومة من الشيطان، وهذا باتفاق الأمة
>
> The dreams of the Prophets are revelation, as they are protected from the devil, the Ummah is agreed upon this.
>
> <sup>— [Madarij as-Saalikin](https://shamela.ws/book/8370/49)</sup>